# MYSQL Can WHERE IN default to ALL if no rows returned

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Have a existing table of results like this;

```
race_id    race_num  racer_id  place
   1           0        32       2
   1           1        32       3
   1           2        32       1
   1           3        32       6
   1           0        44       2
   1           1        44       2
   1           2        44       2
   1           3        44       2
   etc...
```

Have lots of PHP scripts that access this table output the results in a nice format.

Now I have a case where I need to output the results for only certain race_nums.
So I have created this table races_included.

```
race_view   race_id  race_num
   Day 1       1        0
   Day 1       1        1
   Day 2       1        2
   Day 2       1        3
```

And can use this query to get the right results.

```
SELECT racer_id, place from results WHERE race_id=1 
AND race_num IN
   (SELECT race_num    FROM races_included WHERE race_id='1' AND race_view='Day 1')
```

This is great but I only need this feature for a few races and to have it work in a compatible mode for the simple case show all races.  I need to add alot of rows to the races_included table. Like

```
 race_view   race_id  race_num
   All         1        0
   All         1        1
   All         1        2
   All         1        3
```

95% of my races don't use the daily feature.

So I am looking for a way to change the query so that if for race 1 there are no records in the races_included table it defaults to all races.  In addition I need it to be close the same execution speed as the query without the IN clause, because this query Or variations of it are used a lot.

One way that does work is to redefine the table as races_excluded and use NOT IN.  This works great but is a pain to manage the table when races are added or deleted.

Is there a simple way to use EXISTS and IN in tandem as a subquery to get the desired results?  Or some other neat trick I am missing.

To clarify I have found a working but very slow solution.

```
 SELECT * FROM race_results WHERE race_id=1 
    AND FIND_IN_SET(race_num, (SELECT IF((SELECT Count(*) FROM races_excluded 
    WHERE  rid=1>0),(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rnum) FROM races_excluded 
    WHERE  rid=1  AND race_view='Day 1' GROUP BY rid),race_num)))
```

It basically checks if any records exists for that race_id and if not return a set equal to the current race_num  and if yes returns a list of included race nums.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `or` in the subquery:

```
SELECT racer_id, plac
from results
WHERE race_id = 1 AND
      race_num IN (SELECT race_num
                   FROM races_included
                   WHERE race_id = '1' AND (race_view = 'Day 1' or raw_view = 'ANY')
                  );
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  I would rather not have any records in the results include table for a race that doesn't use this feature.